# Error from Instrument when plugin my iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, instruments

When I try to profile my application with instruments, when it launches, it displays this annoying message:

```
The device '<my device>' has a date and/or time 
set too distant from the host machine.
Please detach the device, set the time correctly, 
and then re-attach the device to use with Instruments.
```

I set the time automatically, and it's the same than my machine. I tried to detach and re attach, to reboot etc... but it keep on happening.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Reset your mobile device date time.

I got the same problem,and resolved by reseting my iPad date format for“12h” to “24h”, just like the mac date format.